# Add and Edit Business or Location in own OSM Tile Server

Tags: python, openstreetmap

Looking for Map Making Client or Python Code to add or edit business, plot areas on self-hosted OSM Tile Server

I have successfully built the OSM Tile Server on Google Compute Engine. I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-18-04-osm). This is working fine in our web sites/application. We want to add more business or address locations in our map database. This is private data. Are there any map-making tools to add business or location in our DB? It would be great if we have any python code or API to add locations in the existing Postgres DB.

Comment: Can anybody help on this, please